# How to replace "\" with "\\" from a string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried `mystring.replace(/\\/g,"\\")` but that didn't work. 
Can someone advise me how to do this replacement?

Example:  `String = "C:\Users\Test\FileName"`

When I replace `\` with `\\`, I need to see a result as follows:

`C:\\Users\\Test\\FileName`

Comment: `mystring.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")` <- `"\\\\"` = \\

Comment: Have you tried logging `mystring` before replacing? You aren't escaping those backslashes in your sample

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You mean four backslashes in the regex? Not with the regex literal syntax (`/regex/flags`)

Answer (score 4):

Inside string `\`-backslash is used to escape the following character. In the string, `"C:\Users\Test\FileName"` also backslash is used as escape sequence and actual string is `"C:UsersTestFileName"`

```js
var str = "C:\Users\Test\FileName";
console.log(str);
```

To make this correct, the backslashes in the string should already escaped.

```
var str = "C:\\Users\\Test\\FileName";
```

```js
var str = "C:\\Users\\Test\\FileName";
console.log(str);
```

The regex can now be used to double the backslashes

```
str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
```

```js
var str = "C:\\Users\\Test\\FileName";
console.log(str);
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use raw string,`String.raw()` method is a tag function of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
String.raw`\"`.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');
```

or,if first one isn't work,try this :) hope this will be helped to you

```
String.raw\".replace(/\\"/g, '\\"');
```